# Sql query to count values after a particular condition is met

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table,

```
Name   Seconds  Status_measure
a      0           10
a      10          13
a      20          -1
a      30          15
a      40          20
a      50          12
a      60          -1
```

Here I want for a particular name a new column which is calculated by, "The number of times the value goes >-1 only after once the -1 is met" . So in this particular data I want a new column for the name "a" which has the value=3 , because once the -1 is reached in Status_measure, we have 3 values (15 and 20 and 12)>-1

Required data frame:

```
Id   Name   Seconds  Status_measure    Value
1    a      0           10                3
2    a      10          13                3
3    a      20          -1                3
4    a      30          15                3
5    a      40          20                3
6    a      50          12                3
7    a      60          -1                3
```

I tried doing

```
count(status_measure>-1) over (partition by name order by seconds)
```

But this is not giving any desired result

Comment: Can your "*Value*" field assume different values or just one? What happens when you have multiple "count ranges" among your values, which do you pick, the lowest, the highest, any else according to other logic?

Comment: Actually I just want the number of times the status_measure has gone greater than -1 after the first -1 in the column for a particular name. So i used partition by Name. And the "Value" field assumes only 1 value per Name value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in 2 steps, group data, count entries of the grp = 1.

```
  select *, sum(Status_measure > -1 and grp = 1) over(partition by name) n
  from (
    select *
    , row_number() over(partition by name order by Seconds) - sum(Status_measure > -1 ) over(partition by name order by Seconds) grp
    from tbl 
   ) t
```

Answer (score 1):

An option is using a variable update, which:

- starts from 0
- increases its value when reaches a -1
- decreases its value when reaches a second -1

Once you have this column, you can run a sum over your values.

```
SET @change = 0;

SELECT *, SUM(CASE WHEN Status_measure = -1
                   THEN IF(@change=0, @change := @change + 1, @change := @change - 1)
                   ELSE @change END) OVER() -1 AS Value_
FROM tab
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nrhEEw8u4bdsWxz6hyVn4U/2).

Limitations: this solution assumes you have only one range of interesting values between -1s.

**Note**: there's a -1 decrement from your sum because the first update of the variable will leave 1 in the same row of -1, which you don't want. For better understanding, comment out the application of `SUM() OVER` and see intermediate output.

Comment: My comment in the comments section was exactly about more clarification on the nature of OP's values. This solution works with OP's shared data.

Answer (score 0):

More of a clarification to your question first.  I want to expand your original data to include another row for the sake of 2 vs 3 entries.  Also, is there some auto-increment ID in your data that the sequential consideration is applicable such as

```
Id   Name   Seconds  Status_measure    Value
1    a      0           10                3
2    a      10          13                3
3    a      20          -1                3
4    a      30          15                3
5    a      40          20                3
6    a      50          12                3
7    a      60          -1                3
```

If sequential, and you have IDs 1 & 2 above the -1 at ID #3.  This would indicate two entries.  But then for IDs 4-6 above -1 have a count of three entries before ID #7.

So, what "VALUE" do you want to have in your result.  The max count of 3 for all rows, or would it be a value of 2 for ID#s 1, 2 and 3?   And value of 3 for Ids 4-7?  Or, do you want ALL entries to recognize the greatest count before -1 measure to show 3 for all entries.

Please EDIT your question, you can copy/paste this in your original question if need be and provide additional clarification as requested (auto-increment as well as that is an impact of final output / determining break).

Comment: As you pointed out , I edited and I do want the value of 3